# Is sysctl() system call considered private API in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, system-calls

I was intending to use the `sysctl()` and `uname()` system calls from an iOS Application to get system related information. 
Are these system calls considered private? Will it cause any rejections to the submitted application?

Also in a more generic sense, Are there any guidelines to identify private APIs before submitted the iOS App?